# local in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am reading about local definitions in the book, and I came across this example-

```
(local ((define (f x) (+ x 5))
    (define (g alon)
      (cond
        [(empty? alon) empty]
        [else (cons (f (first alon)) (g (rest alon)))])))
  (g (list 1 2 3)))
```

what exactly does `local` do here?

Comment: This looks like a let binding... a la http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html.  I haven't seen "local" before, but it looks like it should do the same thing as let, namely define f and g only locally for the call (g (list 1 2 3)) but not make it accessible to other parts of the code.  Is that what you meant or is something else going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`local` is documented either in [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=local#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._local%29%29) as part of one of the HtDP languages or in [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html?q=local) as part of the `local` module. Let's see each one in turn. First the one in HtDP:

> `(local [definition ...] expression)` Groups related definitions for use in expression. Each definition can be either a define or a define-struct. When evaluating local, each definition is evaluated in order, and finally the body expression is evaluated. Only the expressions within the local (including the right-hand-sides of the definitions and the expression) may refer to the names defined by the definitions. If a name defined in the local is the same as a top-level binding, the inner one “shadows” the outer one. That is, inside the local, any references to that name refer to the inner one.

And next, the one in the `local` module:

> `(local [definition ...] body ...+)` Like letrec-syntaxes+values, except that the bindings are expressed in the same way as in the top-level or in a module body: using define, define-values, define-syntax, struct, etc. Definitions are distinguished from non-definitions by partially expanding definition forms (see Partial Expansion). As in the top-level or in a module body, a begin-wrapped sequence is spliced into the sequence of definitions.

So depending on the language/modules in use, you'll know which `local` was the one you found. And clearly, it's not a standard special form.

Answer (score 1):

Local used to define some helper functions in the scope of a specific function. For example I am writing a function to add 5 to all elements of the given list ,

```
(define (add-5-to-list list)
    (local
        ( ;; definition area start
         (define (f x) (+ x 5))
         (define (g alon)
            (cond
               [(empty? alon) empty]
               [else (cons (f (first alon))
                           (g (rest alon)))]))
        ) ;; definition area end
        (g list)
    ) ;; local end
) ;; define end
```

You can define as many function as you like in local. But you can use only in the scope of the main function (here the main function is add-5-to-list).