# Define queue in a function

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a new queue in one of my functions, but I am getting error

> define: found a definition that is not at the top level

How can I resolve this? I need to create this queue somewhere inside. I cannot just create auxiliary variables outside of it.

```
(define (bfs-graph X G)
  (define q (make-queue))
  (enqueue! q X)
  ... some work with queue
  )

(define (reachable? X Y G)
  (cond
    [(empty? (graph-edges G)) #f]
    [else (bfs-graph X G)]
    )
  )
```

EDIT:

Ok, this seems like it works. I will try to play with the code some more. Thanks.

```
(define (reachable? X Y G)
  (let ((q (make-queue)))
    (cond
      [(empty? (graph-edges G)) #f]
      [else (bfs-graph X G q)]
      )
    )
  )


(define (bfs-graph X G q)
  (enqueue! q X)
  )
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new, different queue each time `bfs-graph` is called, or to reuse the same queue between different invocations of `bfs-graph?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I am gonna reuse bfs-graph recursively. I am trying to as you might have guessed to find all neighbours of a given vertex and I am putting them in a queue, so I would like to have the same queue that I could append with new values.

Comment: Then it's a better idea to create the queue _outside_ the procedure and pass it along as a parameter from the procedure that starts the computation.

Comment: So for example in the reachable predicate and pass it to the bfs-graph alongside with X and G?

Comment: Yes, I think that'd be enough. And make sure to pass the queue in the recursive calls.

Comment: I have just edited my question with your proposed solution. Did I get it wrong? The function is not defined in the bfs-graph method.

Comment: Did you misspell `enqueue!` as `!enqueue`?

Comment: yea...that was awkward. I really need some sleep I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted should work, try changing the language - set it to "Determine language from source" and add this line at the beginning of the file:

```
#lang racket
```

If for some reason you can't use a different language, this is equivalent to what you wrote:

```
(define (bfs-graph X G)
  (let ((q (make-queue)))
    (enqueue! q X)
    ; ... some work with queue
    ))
```

Comment: I should have probably said that I am using "Advanced Student" in DrRacket. Your solution works now but I have a question. I found out I could also use local() isntead of let. What are the differences? Also when I input more "(enqueue! q 5)" after each other, it invokes this error : `let: expected only one expression after the bindings, but found 1 extra part`

Comment: They're more or less the same, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15236960/201359) for a bit more of info on `local`. I'd rather use `let`, it's standard Scheme. The error you're receiving is surely caused by some misplaced parentheses, please take a look at [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) to make sure you're using the syntax correctly.

Comment: You can use `(local [(define q (make-queue))] (begin (enqueue! q X) .... some work with q ....))`.

Comment: In the Advanced Student language, I would recommend using `local`, not `let`. In the teaching languages you're meant to use `local` because you can re-use the existing syntax for `define`.

Comment: I see, but if I wanted to use the queue across multiple methods like in my original question, would that still work if it was in local? I thought that the variables in local are accesssible only from local.

Comment: What do you mean? If you define `q` in a local, than `q` is accessible anywhere in the scope of the local. But the `enqueue!` function is accessible anywhere in the file, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's what I meant. If I made `q` in the `reachable?` predicate and passed it as a parameter to `bfs-graph`, then if I would be able to access it. But It's true that all I am going to need is `enqueue` and `dequeue` so that should not be a problem right?